# Problem with Crystal report and connection to database - oracle

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, oracle10g

i have Oracle 10g database that connect to my C# program, and i have crystal report that connect to this 
database.
in my computer all work excelent !!, in customer computer the program works - except the crystal report.
what can be the problem ?

thank's in advance

Comment: You need to provide details about the report not working.  First suspect is the TNS name

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the customer has oracle client installed depending on your senario.Maybe you have it one you machine that is why it works.